# For B1-b2 ( business) Visa for Indians - non-immigrant visa

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I will be traveling to US and need to apply for B2 Visa sponsored by my employer. In the supporting documents I have seen the ask for tax payments proof. I have last FY 2017-18 tax proof and also getting one done for FY 2018-19. They have asked for last 2 years. Would this suffice?
Do Visa officers check tax returns if sponsored by employer?

Comment: Welcome.  The title of your question says "B1" but the body says "B2."   If you're traveling for work, the title is correct.

Comment: You should just select B1/B2, instead of one or the other; virtually everyone gets this.

Comment: B-2 visas do not allow business visits.  You need a B-1  visa or a combination B-1/B-2 visa.  None of this addresses your actual question, though, to which I do not know the answer.

Comment: Yes I meant b1-b2 Visa but the question was more around the tax returns for non-immigrant temporary visit to us sponsored by my employer